# Why is the capacitance of a short infinite?

Tags: capacitance

The voltage across a short is 0. It also does not store any charge. So the capacitance of a short is 0/0. However, I am told the capacitance of a short is infinite. How can this be?

Comment: The capacitance of a short is actually infinite, not zero. In other words, an infinite capacitor is indistinguishable from a short circuit. Zero capacitance represents an open circuit. So what is your actual question?

Comment: @Dave Tweed Ok then my question is why is the capacitance of a short infinite

Comment: While it seems to me to be 0/0

Comment: It's  the mathematical concept of limit, capacitors bigger and bigger will have current flowing, charge stored but tiny voltage across. So it would behave pretty much as a short circuit, but it's not a short circuit. I.e. one function tends to some value approaching limit, but it's not defined at limit itself.

Comment: An infinite capacitor is a perfect sink. You can pour stuff into it for ever and a day and it just disappears.

Comment: What's the definition of capacitance?

Comment: @DaveTweed An infinite capacitance isn't always indistinguishable from a short circuit. If it's already charged to some voltage, it's indistinguishable from a perfect voltage source with the source resistance of a short circuit.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Yes, I think we've had this conversation before. You are quite correct. A similar thing could be said about an infinite inductor that already has a current flowing through it: it's indistinguishable from a current source in parallel with an open circuit.

Comment: The only way it would make sense is C=infinite as when you look at the cut frequency equation of a RC circuit i.e. fc=1/(2*pi*RC), when you replace C by a short, it either cuts all the frequencies or passes all the frequencies, so the only solution is C->infinite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The voltage across a short circuit is zero, regardless of current.

There are three components this could be modelled as, which also have zero AC voltage across them regardless of AC current, they are

a) A resistor with zero resistance
b) A capacitor with infinite capacitance
c) An inductor with zero inductance

However, these components aren't equivalent.

At DC, a capacitor can have a steady voltage across it, storing energy, and able to deliver that energy into a load.

At DC, an inductor can have a steady current through it, storing energy, and able to deliver that energy into a load.

Obviously therefore, a short circuit only *is* a zero ohm resistance, as it doesn't store energy.

However, if you are doing an AC analysis, and have a large value decoupling capacitor, it's often convenient to model it as 'an AC short circuit', as its series impedance will be very small with respect to the surrounding components.

Comment: But, you still don't say why a short can be modelled as an infinite capacitance

Comment: why would you want to model a short as a capacitor (inf or zero). Look at it like this... you model a short as a capacitor... it doesn't matter how much current you pump into this short the VOLTAGE does not change:  i = C dv/dt thus C is infinite. But again... why model a short as a capacitor

Comment: All I am asking is why I am getting 0/0, which is clearly wrong

Comment: 0/0 *is* infinity, if you like. It's also zero, or any other number you care to think of. What that means is expressing something as 0/0 is not going to tell you anything about it, and you have to approach it form some other direction.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose someone hands you a black box with two terminals poking out the sides.  They tell you that they have just invented an infinite capacitor.

We can take the equation *C = Q/V*, and rearrange it as *V = Q/C*.  It also makes things easier to use *Q = It*, where *I* is the current and *t* the time you apply the current for.  This gives us *V = It/C*.

So you connect the black box up to a power supply, and pass a known current through it.  After some time *t*, you observe that the voltage across the box is still zero.

You suspect that the box is really just a short circuit.

But the box's inventor points out that if *C* is infinite, then *V* will always be zero regardless of how long you pass a (finite) current through it.

In other words, it's impossible to tell the difference between a short circuit and an infinite capacitor.

Comment: What does Q = It mean in this context

Comment: Q is charge "passing through" any cross-section of the short ryt, not charge "stored across" any part of the wire

Comment: @Truth-seek Q = Total amount of charge that has passed through a point.  This is equal to the current multiplied by the time.

Comment: Exactly. "Passed through" a point, not stored anywhere. Capacitance is storing charge rather than letting them pass throught, ryt??

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be basing your question on the formula
$$C = \frac{Q}{V}$$
Or more correctly,
$$C = \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta V}$$
This formula tells you that you can measure a capacitance by trying to charge it — you can either put some charge on it and measure the resulting change in voltage, or you can apply a voltage and measure the charge that moves as a result.

You then correctly assert that \$V\$ across a short is zero. However, you also assert that \$Q\$ is also zero, which is incorrect. The fact is that you can put arbitrarily large amounts of charge through a short, so \$\Delta Q\$ is definitely some nonzero value. A nonzero value divided by zero is infinity, the effective value of capacitance for the short.

Similarly, when you have an open circuit, you can put an arbitrarily large amount of voltage on it but zero charge will move through it. Now you have zero divided by a nonzero number, which gives you an effective value for the capacitance of zero.

In neither case do you get a situation of dividing zero by zero. That would simply mean that you had not yet attempted to measure the capacitance.

Comment: Short does not "store" charge in the same way as a capacitor, ryt?? It was currents throught it, which is moving charge, not stored charge??

Comment: Charge is charge. See my additional notes above.

Answer (score 1):

A short is not a capacitor, so it doesn't make sense to try to determine how much capacitance it has.

You can say that a capacitance approaches a short as the capacitance goes towards infinity.  I'm not sure how useful this is in any practical sense, though.  It's also not the same as saying a short is a infinite capacitance.

---

A short is sortof like a mathematical singularity.  You can't start there and say what it is.  You can only say how certain things have to be modified to get there.

A resistance approaches a short as the resistance goes towards 0.

A inductance approaches a short as the inductance goes towards 0.

A capacitance approaches a short as the capacitance goes toward infinity.

None of the above is more right or wrong than any other.  Trying to flip these around isn't really correct.  A short isn't any more or less a 0 resistance than a 0 inductance than a infinite capacitance.

Comment: But, I have been told stuff like short has infinite capacitance, or zero resistance or zero inductance

Comment: @Tru: People say lots of stuff.  What's the real point here?  What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I solved the problem I was trying to solve. It was a shorted capacitor. I knew that since all the current flows through the short, the capacitor remains uncharged. A shorted capacitor is thus equivalent to no capacitor at all.

Comment: But, this means a short should have infinite capacitance, since infinity in parallel with a capacitance would give net capacitance of infinity

Comment: @Tru: *"A shorted capacitor is thus equivalent to no capacitor at all."* Or a infinite one, depending on how you look at it.  This is the ambiguity you get when dividing by 0.  It's really pointless to try to think of a short this way.